# Поиск и замена в txt

Tags: c#, поиск, text, замена

Всем привет! 
Столкнулся со следующей задачей.
Есть документ формата txt

```
7200
20 1 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.570136 2.51 2.63
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
20 2 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.572938 2.51 2.63
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
20 3 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.615161 2.57 2.65
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
```

В первой строке число 7200 - т.е. это количество блоков. 
Далее есть строки

```
20 1 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
20 2 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
20 3 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
и т.д. 7200 раз
```

Вот в этих строках мне нужно заменить цифру 20 на цифру 160
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75387/discussion-on-question-by-englishman-----txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам регулярное выражение, которое ищет "20", которое стоит в начале строки, а после него следует ровно 8 групп из символов цифр, знаков +-, точки или буквы E разделенных пробелом и с переводом строки: `(?<=^)20(?=( [0-9\-\+E\.]+){8}\r?$)`

Проверить можно так:

```
var input = @"7200
20 1 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.570136 2.51 2.63
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0.15013 0 0 2.570136 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
20 2 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.572938 2.51 2.63
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
0 -1.425686 0 2.572938 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
20 3 4 -65 -25 1000 -1000 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038
0 0 0 0 0
2.615161 2.57 2.65
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1
-1.425686 -2.708803 0 2.615161 -3.4E+038 3.4E+038 1 1";
var pattern = @"(?<=^)20(?=( [0-9\-\+E\.]+){8}\r?$)";
var replacement = "160";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Для загрузки входной строки из файла используйте `File.ReadAllText`, а для записи `File.WriteAllText`, итого ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
var filename = "...";
var input = File.ReadAllText(filename);
var pattern = @"(?<=^)20(?=( [0-9\-\+E\.]+){8}\r?$)";
var replacement = "160";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText(filename, result);
```

Универсальный шаблон, если число, которое необходимо заменить, может быть любым (целым неотрицательным):

```
var pattern = @"(?<=^)\d+(?=( [\d\-\+E\.]+){8}\r?$)";
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75404/discussion-on-answer-by--nop-----txt).